# What exact type of audio format (number of samples per second, number of bits per sample) is produced by PhoneGap audio recording (e.g. in iOS)?

Tags: cordova, audio-recording, sampling, audioformat

I know that in iOS and in Android, wav and amr files are generated rispectively, but I ignore all details (sampling frequency, bits, ...).  I'm interested in iOS and Android at first.
Someone can help me?
Sorry for my "guessed" english.